# Who do the job of ViewResolver in Spring4 Rest Controller? & who render views after request?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Simple Controller & Tiles View Resolver => it works

```
/**
 * For Exple:
 * Spring Controller
 * & Tiles View Resolver
 * It Works Well
 */
@Controller
public class Home {
  @Autowired
  private IManager<BaseObject> manager;
  public void setManager(IManager<BaseObject> manager) {
      this.manager = manager;
  } 
  @RequestMapping(value = "/listprovider", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String listProvider(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("listprovider",this.manager.getAllProvider());
      return "listProviderPage";
      // listProviderPage ==> the name of the rendered (Tiles)View.
      // it works well
  }
}
```

But with RestController the render is only a JSON not a view page, I want to render the view page & JSON data both.

```
/**
 * But with
 * Spring4 RestController
 * 
 */
@RestController
public class Home {
  @Autowired
  private IManager<BaseObject> manager;
  public void setManager(IManager<BaseObject> manager) {
      this.manager = manager;
  } 
  @RequestMapping(value = "/listprovider", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String listProvider() {
      return this.manager.getAllProvider(); // Message Converter To Json
      // what about the view?
      // what is the secret of view resolver in **Spring Rest**
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RestController is the combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody.

When you use @RestController , response gets converted in Json format implicitly and there is no need to declare @ResponseBody explicitly.

It is defined to send only the data in defined formats and retrieval of any view is not possible using it.

If you want to retrieve page from @restcontroller , you need to use ModelandView or
write a new controller and annotate with @Controller and return view name so it will look for view resolver and render the appropriate page.

You need to configure view resolver like below in spring configuration file

```
@Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        res.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return res;
    }
```

So when you return page name from controller, view resolver look for appropriate jsp page in WEB-INF folder and return view.

Below link for reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html

Comment: I know this Vaibs, but the question is how manage views with Spring Rest Controller? who/what is the responsable for render views in Spring Rest ? how make the MAPPING between coming request & views respense?